# Why can't I put background img/color in my code?

Tags: html, css

I can't put anything in my background

```css
.body {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("tlostronki.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  height: 900px;
  width: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: burlywood;
  border-radius: 9%;
  margin-top: 65px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-left: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.item1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-radius: 7%;
  left: 23%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
  background: grey;
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: transform 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  ;
}

.item1:hover:hover {
  border-color: rgb(51, 65, 70);
  border: 3px solid;
  color: inherit;
  position: relative;
  transition: 370ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  width: 320px;
  height: 430px;
  top: -15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px, 2px 2px 0px darkgrey, 3px 3px 0px darkgrey, 4px 4px 0px darkgrey, 5px 5px 0px #56542a;
  background: grey;
}

.h1 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.p1 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
}

.container2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("tlostronki.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"><img src="example photo.png"></div>
  <div class="h1">
    <h1>Semestr 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="p1">
    <p1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis,
      turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis. Phasellus congue
      lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa
      nibh nec erat.</p1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Learn to use your browser devtools inspect facility which will let you see exactly what CSS is being applied to each element.

Comment: I suppose .body is a class for an element in your HTML otherwise if you are targetting the body tag just remove the dot and the position absolute. In your case here put the file tlostronki.png in the same folder as your css file.

Answer (score 0):

There are below mistakes in code

- You have a `<p1>` tag in your HTML, but it should be `<p>`
- In your CSS, .body should be body without the dot (.). You're targeting the  tag, not a class named body.
- In .item1:hover:hover, you only need one :hover pseudo-class.
- Make sure your background image paths are correct.

Comment: what tag is it ?

Comment: correct <p1> tag to <p>

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you put ".body" .
body is not a class! use "body{}

Comment: it's not your question but you could not use background position in background-image property. You must use background : url() +  your position